# Shut down all VMs on XenServer 6.5.0

Tags: citrix, xenserver

I know that there is a command in the XenServer-CLI to shut down a specific VM.

```
xe vm-shutdown vm=<VMNAME>
```

It works fine, but I can only shut down one VM at at time. Is there something like a wildcard or another command to shut down **all** VMs on the Host simultaneously?

Answer (score 2):

The proper command to shutdown **ALL** VMs is:

> xe vm-shutdown **--multiple**

This is known to work (at least) for XenServer 6.5 and 7

Answer (score 0):

If you do not specify the `vm=` parameter, Xen automatically stops all running VMs.

The following command would be correct (for a non-pooled XenServer)

```
xe vm-shutdown
```